# Photoshop: How to render a text layer to separate words as pictures with a script?

Tags: script, adobe-photoshop

My problem comes from trying to design watchfaces for different smart watches.
Here you often need the text elements as single images with a given color depth, e.g. the numbers 0-9 and the weekdays as Mo Tu We etc.
This can be a very annoying job if you recognize that you like to try your text increased by one point and with another font - you always start at point zero :-P

Is it possible with a Photoshop script that I give it a text layer with the needed elements, separated by e.g. a space and the script gets the elements one by one, make a new document, paste it in, rasterize the text and save it?
This would be a huge time saver...

Comment: Should be doable. If you can perform it manually, you can record that to an action and run it.

Comment: Alternatively, you could make a script that  loops through layouts, identifying the text layers, then changing the font and size. If that is a valid approach, then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28948059/photoshop-script-to-change-font-and-font-size#28948270) is a good starting point.

Comment: @LPChip 23: You're right, parts of the task can be recorded as actions but it always needs manual input like selecting the parts.

Comment: It would be great if you have a script and a single text line with a given font and size that contains all parts that are needed as single images, e.g. "Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9" and the script goes through the line and picks "Mo", copy it, paste to a new document, rasterize it and save in a given file format, then picks "Tu" etc.